# Join many tables with one select

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have some tables of different type of orders

- Table orderA

  idA - int, idCustomer - int, propertieA1 - string, propertieA2 - int
  ...
- Table orderB

  idB - int, idCustomer - int, propertieB1 - real, propertieB2 - int ...
- Table orderC

  idC - int, idCustomer - int, propertieC1 - string, propertieC2 - string...

and a table of cutomers

- Table customer

  idCustomer - int, name string, address - string...

Now I want to select all the orders of a particular customer. How can I do it?
I thought to do a select like this:

```
SELECT * FROM customer 
INNER JOIN orderA ON orderA.idCustomer = customer.idCustomer 
INNER JOIN orderB ON orderB.idCustomer = customer.idCustomer 
INNER JOIN orderC ON orderC.idCustomer = customer.idCustomer 
WHERE customer.idCustomer = 235
```

But it's giving me all the "orderA" with the first "oredrB", an again all the "orderA" with the second "orderB", and so on.

So if he had 100 orderA, 100 orderB and 100 orderC - the resulf is 100*100*100 rows - a million rows for 300 orders!

How can I fix it? (I can change the structure of the tables if it's necessary)

Thanks

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: in orderA the customer bought a notebook - the string is the name of the company and the int is the size. in orderB the customer bought a Poster - the real is the size in cm and the int is the index. in oredrC he bought a book - the string is the name of the book and the name of the author. the result will be - the cutomer no. 235 bought 5 notebooks, 12 posters and 2 books, with all there details

Comment: @chmouelkalifa . . . You have a ridiculous data structure.  A single `orders` table should have a `productid` reference to another table, with information about products.  Products can have common information such as a name and vendor, and specialized columns, which might be stored as a JSON object if they are not used in the database.

Comment: I think you right that it's better to have a table for the products,, but still I have the same problem with the products itself. I don't know how to work with JSON object, so I still have to build a separate table for each product (or some similar products), and again the join will give me too many results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can change the structure of the tables . . . then do it!  Put all the orders into a single table, even if you have `NULL` columns because the values do not apply.

If you want all the orders in one table, then you need to carefully choose the columns, and using `union all`. The general structure is:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer c INNER JOIN
     ((SELECT idCustomer, col1, col2, . . .
       FROM orderA
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT idCustomer, col1, col2, . . .
       FROM orderB
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT idCustomer, col1, col2, . . .
       FROM orderC
      )
     ) o
     ON o.idCustomer = c.idCustomer 
WHERE c.idCustomer = 235;
```

You need to decide which columns you want and be sure that each subquery has a value for the column (even if the value is `NULL`).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think there is a problem with your syntax. no? so It's not clear for me.

Comment: @chmouelkalifa . . . The query is a template.  There were a couple of obvious flaws, but it should do what you want.